# ¿Cómo se dice "un ligue de una noche"?

Tags: diferencias-regionales, coloquialismos, sinónimos, vulgaridades

¿Alguien puede decirme cómo se dice "un ligue de una noche" ("booty call" en inglés) en otros dialectos de español?

Comment: ¡Buenas! ¿Te refieres a cómo se dice eso en variantes locales del español de cada país o región? Ten en cuenta que "booty call" no significa lo que propones, por las definiciones del Urban Dictionary veo que se refiere más a cuando en mitad de la noche llamas a alguien para pedirle sexo sin más, lo que implicaría que conoces previamente a esa persona, y no tiene por qué ser un hecho aislado de una noche. Un "rollo de una noche" implica más bien que has conocido a alguien con quien has intimado y no piensas volver a verlo. ¿En qué expresión quieres profundizar?

Answer (score 3):

En España solemos (o solíamos) llamarlo **rollo**:

> [**rollo**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=WdApXKx)
>
> 16. m. coloq. Relación amorosa, generalmente pasajera.

Por ejemplo: *«—¿Es tu novio? —No, es solo un rollo.»*.

Como verbo, y atendiendo a lo que comenta Charlie, tienes ***enrollarse*** que significa:

> [**enrollar(se)**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=FaO1IdN)
>
> 8. prnl. coloq. Entablar una relación amorosa o erótica, normalmente pasajera. *Se ha enrollado CON alguien mayor que él.*

Esto de 'enrollarse' quizá se acerca más al concepto de *booty call* que el que has propuesto de 'ligue', ya que sirve tanto para hablar de diferentes "rollos" en el sentido de diferentes relaciones y personas, como para hablar de enrollarse varias veces con la misma persona en diferentes momentos, por un calentón o porque os apetece, sin que por ello exista (digan lo que digan *les amigues*) una relación estable.

Aunque si estamos hablando específicamente de una persona con la que nos *enrollamos* de vez en cuando por puro placer pero con la que no tenemos relación romántica, podemos emplear la comúnmente usada (pero aún no admitida) [*follamigo o follamiga*](https://es.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Follamigo&redirect=no).

Answer (score 2):

México (Norte) un *booty call* es simplemente un ***acostón*** con tu ***cogiamigo(a)***, el *one night stand* es un ***acostón*** y ya.

En inglés, *booty call* suele usarse como sustantivo también (*I'll see my booty call tonight*) y en este caso directamente se trata de  ***cogiamigo (a)*** ("esta noche veré a mi cogiamigo")

El referirse a esto así "directo y sin anestesia" es algo *muy del norte* aunque en todo el país se entenderá de lo que se trata sin mayor explicación. Sin embargo es rarísimo que alguien siquiera haga una mención casual al sexo si no es en algún contexto de *albur* o de plano  en algún insulto *altisonate* o soez.

Si acaso se hace alguna referencia, sin entrar a detalles de las circunstancias o identidad de los involucrados se usaría cualquier rebuscado eufemismo que esté de moda en en grupo social y región donde uno se encuentre, pero para eufemismos sexuales "nos pintamos" solos en México.

Algunos de estos eufemismos:

1. Un *palito* (o algo que suene así: *paliacate, palenque etc*)
2. *Poner(le)* con alguien ( Le *puso* con fulanita(o), Se fue a *ponerle* con tal, Le está *poniendo* con cuál, etc)
3. Ir a lo *oscurito*
4. *Treparse al guayabo*
5. cualquier conjugación del verbo *dar* donde no se especifique el objeto indirecto sobreentiende por el contexto que se trata de sexo
6. algún rebuscado juego de palabras que en contexto implique quedar a solas con otra persona, en este caso no hay reglas y el ingenio para formularios es sorprendente, y hasta hilarante ("fueron a rezar el rosario", "fui a revisar si se habían cocido los tamales", "vamos a *hacer la tarea*" ...etc

Solo basta agregar que se trata de una sola noche u ocasión.

Solo últimamente (90's s. XXI ) se empieza a hablar más abiertamente de sexo fuera de contextos de *albur* o como parte de algún insulto que implique incesto (v.gr mandar a alguien a *chingar a su madre*)

(probablemente en el Caribe Mexicano no sea el caso pues ahí los regionalismos y coloquialismos con frecuencia varían mucho del resto del país)

Answer (score 0):

conozco varios terminos aplicables:

- el levante (de levantar, algo como *to thrill someone*) / el levante de una noche
- el/un ratico
- una comida
- la tirada
- amigo con derechos / amigo especial (o amiga)
- el revuelque
- un huevito / un polvo

Ligar se entiende bien, pero tiene una connotación notoriamente de España, si tu intención es no parecer como tal, puedes utilizar alguno de los términos de arriba, aunque, sin duda habrá para quienes también sean regionalismos.

Comment: ¿Todos son propios de España? La mayoría no me suenan.

Comment: No, quiero decir: "ligar / ligue" es muy de España. Las palabras que escribí no lo son.

Comment: ¿Podrías indicar a qué región pertenece cada cual? Así aprendemos todos :)